# Laravel: CRUD route has a empty parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I'm having a problem with a CRUD route. On my method edit in my controller UserGroupsController, the parameter $userGroup is empty.

UserGroupsController

```
class UserGroupsController extends Controller
{
    public function edit(UserGroup $userGroup)
      {        
        if (Auth::check())
        {
          $users = User::pluck('name','id')->all();
          $groups = Group::pluck('name','id')->all();
          return view('users-group.edit', compact('userGroup','users','groups'));
        }else{
          return redirect('login');
        }

    }
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">Edit</div>
     <div class="panel-body">
          {{ $userGroup }}
          {!! Form::model($userGroup,['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['users-group.update', $userGroup->id], 'id' => 'user_group-form', 'class' => 'form-horizontal'] ) !!}
          {{ csrf_field() }}

          <input type='hidden' name='id' value='{!! $userGroup->id !!}'>
          @include('users-group.form',array('submitButton' => 'Edit User Group'))              
       {!! Form::close()  !!}
</div>
```

form.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="user_id" class="col-md-4 control-label">User</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    {!! form::select('user_id', $users, $userGroup->user_id,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="group_id" class="col-md-4 control-label">Group</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    {!! form::select('group_id', $groups, $userGroup->group_id,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
        {!! Form::submit($submitButton) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['web']], function ()
{
  Route::resource('users','UsersController');
  Route::resource('users-group','UserGroupsController');
  Route::resource('companies','CompaniesController');
});
```

php artisan route:list :

```
|        | POST      | users-group                    | users-group.store   | App\Http\Controllers\UserGroupsController@store                        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users-group/create             | users-group.create  | App\Http\Controllers\UserGroupsController@create                       | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | users-group/{users_group}      | users-group.update  | App\Http\Controllers\UserGroupsController@update                       | web          |
|        | DELETE    | users-group/{users_group}      | users-group.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\UserGroupsController@destroy                      | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users-group/{users_group}      | users-group.show    | App\Http\Controllers\UserGroupsController@show                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users-group/{users_group}/edit | users-group.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\UserGroupsController@edit
```

dd($userGroup):

```
UserGroup {#199 ▼
  #fillable: array:2 [▼
    0 => "user_id"
    1 => "group_id"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

In the file edit.blade.php, I print the variable $userGroup, but returns "[ ]". And I have the same code to UsersControllers, but there works.

When I submit the form, I got this error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php
```

Sorry for the english, I hope that you understand my problem and I can give more information. thanks

Comment: Usually, you get the `id` as a parameter for your controller method.

Comment: Hi, I updated the post, I put dd($userGroup);. The variable is empty :(

Comment: Which url are you trying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `edit` method usually gets an id. To fix your problem, remove the type from the header and get the model in your method:

```
class UserGroupsController extends Controller
{
    public function edit($id)
      {        
        $userGroup = UserGroup::findOrFail($id);
        if (Auth::check())
        {
          $users = User::pluck('name','id')->all();
          $groups = Group::pluck('name','id')->all();
          return view('users-group.edit', compact('userGroup','users','groups'));
        }else{
          return redirect('login');
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's the problem in your code. It is clear from the output of `php artisan route:list` that the name of the parameter, the edit function in UserGroupsController was expecting was `$users_group` and not `$userGroup`. So I propose you two simple solution.

**Solution #1**
Change the edit function of UserGroupsController like this.

```
class UserGroupsController extends Controller
{
    public function edit(UserGroup $user_group)
      {        
        if (Auth::check())
        {
          $users = User::pluck('name','id')->all();
          $groups = Group::pluck('name','id')->all();
          return view('users-group.edit', compact('userGroup','users','groups'));
        }else{
          return redirect('login');
        }

    }
}
```

or

**Solution #2**
Change your routes function so that `php artisan route:list` will output this.

```
|        | POST      | users-group                    | users-group.store   | App\Http\Controllers\UserGroupsController@store                        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users-group/create             | users-group.create  | App\Http\Controllers\UserGroupsController@create                       | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | users-group/{userGroup}      | users-group.update  | App\Http\Controllers\UserGroupsController@update                       | web          |
|        | DELETE    | users-group/{userGroup}      | users-group.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\UserGroupsController@destroy                      | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users-group/{userGroup}      | users-group.show    | App\Http\Controllers\UserGroupsController@show                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users-group/{userGroup}/edit | users-group.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\UserGroupsController@edit
```

Remark that `users_group` has to be changed to `userGroup`.

***Ok it works, But why?***

This is beacuse of [Laravel's Implicit Route Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding). Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name. For example:

```
Route::get('api/users/{user}', function (App\User $user) {
    return $user->email;
});
```

Since the `$user` variable is type-hinted as the `App\User` Eloquent model and the variable name matches the `{user}` URI segment, Laravel will automatically inject the model instance that has an ID matching the corresponding value from the request URI. If the variable name does not match the {user} URI segment, Laravel will not inject any model instance and therefore the variable will be left **empty**.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass an object via http. you can either do one of these:

1- get the id as the input and find the record (like what @Daan Meijer said).

2- Use Route Model Binding (Recommended): [Route Model Binding](https://scotch.io/tutorials/cleaner-laravel-controllers-with-route-model-binding)

Comment: @DaanMeijer. Yea. You're gonna love it

Answer (score 0):

By changing the variable name  $userGroup to $usergroup (note the lowercase 'G', matching the resource route naming).So the resource return the data form the database.

In laravel the route variable passed must match the model or controller resource recieved

Answer (score 0):

If your table name in Database is **users_group** *(underscore)*, then resource router  should works  for ['index', 'store', 'show', 'create','update','destroy']  with

```
Route::resource('users_group','UserGroupsController');

dd response: #connection: "mysql"
```

**but not with**

```
Route::resource('users-group','UserGroupsController');

dd response: #connection: null
```